Arch KDE - Plasmashell crashes after locking screen and leaving a bit
I am relatively new to Arch and I'm experiencing a problem with KDE
I'm using

KDE Plasma 6.1.1
KDE Frameworks 6.3.0
Qt 6.7.2
Kernel: 6.9.7-zen1-1-zen (64bit) (I use linux-zen kernel)
Wayland

Whenever I lock my screen and leave for a bit (long enough that the screen turns black), and unlock, plasmashell always has crashed
I used the crash report viewer to get this error log
https://pastebin.com/Z8BmVzsW
I can start plasmashell again by opening the console using CTRL+ALT+T and running "plasmashell" again, but its still annoying
Anyone got an idea what could be the problem? I already ran pacman -Syu to update everything to the newest version
Thanks!

Apparently this is a known problem with display port, after reporting it to the KDE Bugtracker I was told it would be fixed in Qt 6.7.3 in August
